# Pull back and intersection of divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over complex numbers. Let $Z$ be a smooth closed subscheme of $X$. Let $L$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$. Then $L|_Z=E$ is a very ample line bundle on $Z$. If $D,D'\in |E|$ are divisors on $Z$ such that $D\cap D'$ has codimension 2 in $Z$, can we say that $D$ and $D' $ come from divisors in $|L|$ on $X$ whose intersection has codimension 2?

Comment: Not in general. In fact, the map $|L|\to |E| $ may not be surjective, so all sorts of things can go wrong.

Comment: @Mohan, can we impose some conditions on $L$ so that the required condition happens. For example, if $L$ gives a projectively normal embedding, then so does $E$. Then $|L|\rightarrow |E|$ is surjective?

Comment: @Mohan, can we say something conversely. That is, by moving lemma, again we can find divisors $Y, Y'\in |L|$ such that $Y\cap Y'$ has codimension 2 in $X$. Consider the pull back of the corresponding sections, and consider the divisors in $|E|$. Maybe they will have codimension 2 in $D$?

Comment: For your first question, even if $L$ is projectively normal, that does not imply $E$ is. If you just want some divisors in $|L|$ which intersect $D$ in the right codimension, Bertini will do that.

Comment: @Mohan, can you please tell me how by Bertini we can get that?

Comment: $L$ embeds $X$ in projective space. For a general linear subspce of the projective space of codimension $r$, the intersection with $Z$ has codimension $r$ in $Z$ by Bertini. In your case, take $r=2$.